# FileNotFoundError when attempting to move files into a temp directory

Tags: python, file, shutil, temporary-directory

I am attempting to move files inside of a subdirectory into a temp folder. Here is my code:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempDirectory:
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDestination, topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            shutil.move(file, tempDirectory)
```

When I look at my debugger I can see the values of the file variable holding the files I want to move. But nothing moves and I am then given the error FileNotFoundError that references the file I want to move. When I look into my file explorer I can see that the file did not move.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own. So even though file variable was holding the filename it was not holding the entire path to the file. The below code works:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDestination, topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            fileName = os.path.join(fileDestination+"\\"+file)
            print(fileName)
            shutil.move(fileName, tempDirectory)
```